# No data has been received from Functionbeat yet

Tags: aws-lambda, kibana, amazon-cloudwatch, elastic-stack, functionbeat

I have installed and configured functionbeat on the elk server.
Installation and configuration was successful but unable to pull logs on kibana.

[Please Click here to look at the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfmGg.png)

**functionbeat.yml :**

```html
functionbeat.provider.aws.endpoint: "s3.amazonaws.com"
functionbeat.provider.aws.deploy_bucket: "abcde"

functionbeat.provider.aws.functions:
  - name: cloudwatch-logs
    enabled: true
    type: cloudwatch_logs

    triggers:
      - log_group_name: abcdef

# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  host: "pri.ip:5601"

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["http://pri.ip:9200"]

  username: "******"
  password: "**********"

# Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publish", "service".
logging.selectors: ["*"]
```

**the output of the request GET _cat/indices/functionbeat-***

```html
yellow open functionbeat-7.10.2-2021.11.02-000001 mPkuXT1rSDaxsKEM0MUI2A 1 1 0 0 208b 208b
```

**the output of the request GET functionbeat-*/_search?size=1**

```html
{
  "took" : 11,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have installed and configured functionbeat successfully on my elk server so I can integrate AWS cloudwatch logs into elastic's elasticsearch but kibana gives an error  "No data has been received from functionbeat yet."